# Display post title on individual image attachment page

Tags: title

How to display parent post title on individual image attachment page heading of the post gallery? Currently, it shows image name as page heading on image attachment page. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use …

```
echo get_the_title( $post->post_parent );
```

… where `$post` is the currently viewed attachment.