# Show category list on attachment page

Tags: categories

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [categories on attachment page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77390/categories-on-attachment-page)

How can I display post categories on image attachment page  i.e. `image.php`.

I have used [the_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category) function, but it is still blank!!
I guess the problem is that the attachment is not associated with the category of the post?

Thanks

Comment: can you add the code from your image.php file?

Comment: I added this way:
<p>CATEGORY: <?php the_category(', '); ?></p>

Comment: Used with another way as:
 <?php $categories = get_the_category();
          $separator = ', ';
          $output = ''; 
          if($categories){ ?>
          <span>CATERGORY:</span>
    <?php foreach($categories as $category) {
    $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
        }
    echo trim($output, $separator);
        }
        ?>

Comment: Both doesn't show any result!

Comment: are you the same person? -> possible duplicate of [categories on attachment page](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77390/categories-on-attachment-page) - you should be able to deduct the solution via logical deduction from the answer to your recent topic [Display post title on individual image attachment page](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77376/display-post-title-on-individual-image-attachment-page)

Comment: no, I'm wondering who copied this,, I posted this question on some other site a long ago, but noone replied there, so I cam e here!!

Comment: Michael what you said I tried many times but no result!